# How can I tell how charged up a Zarya is?

Tags: overwatch

How can I tell how charged up a friendly or enemy Zarya is? Obviously, if I'm the one who is Zarya, I can just look at my charge level, but for other Zaryas I seem to have to go by how much they're glowing or how wide their beam is.

What are the thresholds where the visual effects for this change?

Answer (score 14):

According to [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/182930-overwatch/73806862) (message 4),

> when Zarya is on the enemy team. She is lightly glowing red when at 50 charge. Heavily glowing at 100, also meaning you typically want to get rid of her quickly before she melts your team.

[image: Zarya begins to glow red as her gun charges]

Comment: "When Zarya hits 100 energy everyone dies" - Seagull

Comment: @sommerjj yea, i hit 100 energy and got a quadruple kill

Comment: I really doubt she is heavily glowing only at 100 though. Generally if you hit 100, you don't stay there long and quickly drop to 99. So maybe the huge glow doesn't turn on until 100, but then when does it turn back off? Back down at 50? I feel like there's more info needed here.

Comment: @Sterno Each 4 points of damage absorbed by a barrier gives you 1 point of charge (decays at 2 points per second). The glow lasts as long as she's being hit, so it actually looks like she's glowing longer if she's getting hit.

Comment: Oh, so even if she's at, say 95 charge, if she's not being hit she doesn't glow?

Comment: @Sterno well, she glows a little, but only as much as she does at >50%. So there isn't really a way of telling if she is at 90% vs 60% but you can tell <50%, >50%, 100%.

Comment: @ChaseC It's actually 3 energy per 5 points absorbed by a barrier, to a maximum of 50 charge for any single barrier cast (even if the full 200 is broken, which would normally net you 120 energy without the cap). Source: http://owinfinity.com/en/hero/zarya/

Comment: A brightly glowing Zarya is my prime target as a Widow Maker.  I suppose someone could use that against me, though, if they paid enough attention. ;)

Comment: @KizTrap Not sure that I've ever heard of owinfinity, but according to reddit research and http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zarya, my information is correct. I'm not sure that I've ever ever seen your numbers.

Comment: @ChaseC The logic behind 1% per 4 points of damage appears to equate to the 50 charge per fully absorbed shield. This is something I can test later by using Junkrat's Trap, then Trap+Mine in separate barrier casts. I'd expect to see 20% from the Trap if going by the 1%:4p ratio, and 50% from Trap+Mine. If going by the 3%:5p ratio, I'd expect to see 48% and 50% respectively.

Comment: @ChaseC Turns out you're right: Junkrat's trap does 80 damage, and I get 20 energy from absorbing it. [proof](https://gfycat.com/GaseousMellowAmericancrayfish)

Comment: @ChaseC I let the author of OWInfinity know, and he's now updating the site with these figures. Saving the world, once SCIENCE!! at a time. Good job! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not only how she's glowing, just think to watch the killcam or ask killed allied to do so, you see the ennemy view, so you can watch how many charge she has (aswell as you can do for the ult). It's not the most usefull way to tell how many charge she has but it's still relevant to tell it to your mates if you are in competitive.

Obviously the glow is more usefull, but every information is relevant when you play seriously.

Comment: side note: some players turn the Kill Cam off since it's disorienting.  It's an option but having a way to read the Zarya before dying is a better choice.

Comment: You just have to press spacebar to quit the killcam, I almost do it everytime before seing anything, it's like a reflex and I don't see any second of the killcam, as if I disabled it. But if I need to give information to my teamate, I still can see the kill cam. I don't think it's necessary to turn it off since you can pass it before it start. But I agree seing before dying is a better option but it's still a plus to use.